# IF formula referencing data in another sheet and a column dropdown list, populating different answers depending on these two variables

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am creating a workbook which will have an executive summary sheet referencing sheets with more specific details. Below is the sheet that I want to reference in a formula to pull in the different costs in Column G and reference tree names in Column A & B.

[image]

Below is an image of the summary sheet where I am wanting to reference the cells in the sheet above. Column D here (titled Cost) is the cell where I am trying to write a formula that changes the price depending on the species name in Column A and the size selected in column B. So essentially I want the formula to check if the species name selected is a Tier One Tree or Tier Two Tree: so if it is in Column A in the other sheet, and Largest, then the formula multiplies G2 by the quantity, or if the species name selected is in Column B as a Tier Two Tree, then the formula multiplies quantity by G6.
[image]

Here is the formula that is in the summary sheet now. The first few arguments are working, but then the half of the arguments using Column B in the other sheet as a reference aren't working. Here is the formula I have now:

`=if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$A$11:$A$250),$B26="SMALL: 15 Gallon/under 6 feet tall/under 1 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$2*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$A$11:$A$250),$B26="MEDIUM: 30 Gallon/6 - 10 ft. tall/1 - 1.9 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$3*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$A$11:$A$250),$B26="LARGE: 2 - 3.4 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$4*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$A$11:$A$250),$B26="LARGEST: 3.5 - 4 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$5*C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$B$11:$B$250),$B26="SMALL: 15 Gallon/under 6 feet tall/under 1 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$6*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$B$11:$B$250),$B26="MEDIUM: 30 Gallon/6 - 10 ft. tall/1 - 1.9 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$7*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$B$11:$B$250),$B26="LARGE: 2 - 3.4 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$8*$C26, if(AND(REGEXMATCH( $A26,'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$B$11:$B$250),$B26="LARGEST: 3.5 - 4 inch caliper"),'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$9*$C26))))))))`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Beside the images, please add some sample data input and the corresponding expected results as text as well a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only.

Answer (score 0):

You want a formula to calculate cost of items taking into account two attributes (Tier and Size).

Consider this formula:

`=if(countif('New Trees/Plants Installation'!$A$11:$A,$A3),if($B3="SMALL: 15 Gallon/under 6 feet tall/under 1 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$2,if($B3="MEDIUM: 30 Gallon/6 - 10 ft. tall/1 - 1.9 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$3,if($B3="LARGE: 2 - 3.4 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$4,$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$5))), if($B3="SMALL: 15 Gallon/under 6 feet tall/under 1 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$6,if($B3="MEDIUM: 30 Gallon/6 - 10 ft. tall/1 - 1.9 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$7,if($B3="LARGE: 2 - 3.4 inch caliper",$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$8,$C3*'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$9))))`

Copy the formula down as many rows as required.

Possibly an `ARRAYFORMULA` could be constructed, but this wasn't a requirement of the OP.

---

The structure is as follows:

1 - if the species is Tier One, then

- if the size = "Small", Cost = Qty by `'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$2`
- if the size = "Medium", Cost = Qty by 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$3`
- if the size = "Large", Cost = Qty by 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$4`
- else the size must be "Largest", so Cost = Qty x 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$5`

2 - if the species isn't Tier One, then

- if the size = "Small", Cost = Qty by `'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$6`
- if the size = "Medium", Cost = Qty by 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$7`
- if the size = "Large", Cost = Qty by 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$8`
- else the size must be "Largest", so Cost = Qty x 'New Trees/Plants Installation'!$G$9`

The formula is simplified by:

- evaluating for "Tier" only once;

  - if the Species isn't Tier One, then it must be Tier Two.
- evaluating size for each Tier

  - Small, Medium and Large
  - if none of the above apply then the size must be "Largest"

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much!